# CodeIgniter not uploading any image when on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload a file in CodeIgniter when on live server. It is working perfectly on localhost but when I try to upload it on live server the upload library is not working, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Do I need to change something in php.ini of live server?

Here is my code:

```
  public function do_upload()
  { 
      $config = [
                'upload_path' =>    './uploads',
                'allowed_types' =>    'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',
                'max_size'            => 1100000000,
                'max_width'            => 102400000,
                'max_height'           => 76800000,
                 ]; 
                 // print_r($config);
                 // exit();
            $upload=     $this->load->library('upload');
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $this->upload->initialize($config); 
         // var_dump($config);
         var_dump($upload);
         // exit();
       if(!$this->upload->do_upload('imagefile')) 
        {
          $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
          $this->load->view('site/timeline/timeline_profile',compact('upload_error'));
        } 
        else
        {
          $post = $this->input->post();
          unset($post['submit']);
          $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
          $file_name=$_FILES['imagefile'];
          $this->load->model('Timeline_model');
          $this->Timeline_model->upload_model($post,$file_name);
          echo $image_path= base_url("uploads/".$upload_data['raw_name'].$upload_data['file_ext']);
        }
  }
```

on var dump the value it is showing me null.

Comment: Logically it should show you nothing because you are dumping $upload which is getting nothing from library load. Either dump $this->upload->data(); in your else statement or $upload_data variable

Comment: tried to do that as well but the values is still null @MalikMudassar

Answer (score 0):

Please follow code in [File Uploading Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) exactly and it will work and make sure you have write permissions to upload folder in your server.

Comment: checked it i can access the path but the upload library is still not working

Comment: check folder permissions